# Get web page text in msgbox

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, com, messagebox

Im trying to get a msgbox to appear once my code has been sent.
I would like to display the inner text.

So far I have

```
 ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.Navigate("http://www.webpage.com.au/")
 ie.Visible = True
 mesg = TextBox1.Text.ToString()
 pw = "....." ie.Document.All("password").Value = pw
 ie.Document.All("idpagers").Value = Id
 ie.Document.All("message").Value = mesg
 ie.Document.All("Send").Click()
 pID = ie.Document.All().ToString

 MessageBox.Show(pID)
```

But this shows *system.object.blah.blah*

Comment: Vb script sorry see i added wrong tag

Comment: The problem is using `ToString()` which just gives you a string representation of the object you call it against hence `System.Object` etc. Use `InnerHTML()` and `innerText()` instead to return either HTML representation of the DOM element or just the Textual representation.

Comment: @Lankymart could you please give an example as an answer so i can mark as answered if correct please

Comment: There are already two answer here that detail using `InnerText()` and `InnerHTML()`, I was just pointing out that `ToString()` doesn't give you what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do 
    wscript.sleep 50            
Loop Until ie.document.readystate = "complete"
```

Put this is after navigate. You have to wait for the page to load.

This assigns html text to a page then extracts plain text.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.Visible = 0
ie.Silent = 1 
ie.Navigate2 "file://" & FilterPath & "Filter.html"
Do 
    wscript.sleep 50            

Loop Until ie.document.readystate = "complete"
ie.document.body.innerhtml = Inp.readall
Outp.write ie.document.body.innertext
```

Comment: I had put this somthing similar in my real one but same outcome

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this code :

```
Const TriStateTrue = -1 ' Pour la prise en charge de l'Unicode
URL = InputBox("Entrez l'URL pour y extraire son Code Source HTML "&vbcr&vbcr&_
"Exemple ""http://www.google.fr""","Extraction du Code Source © Hackoo © 2013","http://www.google.fr")
If URL = "" Then WScript.Quit
Titre = "Extraction du Code Source de " & URL
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ie.Navigate(URL)
ie.Visible=false
DO WHILE ie.busy
LOOP
DataHTML = ie.document.documentElement.innerHTML
strFileHTML = "CodeSourceHTML.txt"
Set objHTMLFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileHTML, 2, True, TriStateTrue)
objHTMLFile.WriteLine(Titre&vbcrLF&String(120,"*"))
objHTMLFile.WriteLine(DataHTML)
objHTMLFile.Close
ie.Quit
Set ie=Nothing
wscript.echo DataHTML
 Ouvrir(strFileHTML)
wscript.Quit

Function Ouvrir(File)
    Set ws=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Notepad.exe "& File,1,False
end Function
```